# How to add an image in an existing pdf in nodejs

Tags: node.js, image, pdf, package

I want to add an image to a existing pdf document in nodejs. I have used many packages but it didn't work out as I have also use jsPDF. Can anyone help me how can i add a image in existing pdf.
Thank You